# Summation error of n-segment Trapezoidal rule

Tags: numerical-methods

Help me please with this question.

Let $f\in C^{\infty }$ function defined as $\forall x, f(x)=f(x+2\pi )$.
Let $e_{n}$ be a summation error of n-segment trapezoidal rule.
Prove that $\forall \alpha \geq 0$, $\exists C>0$ so that:
$\left | e_{n} \right |\leqslant \frac{C}{n^{\alpha }}$

Thanks a lot!